# Matlab - how to extract specific data from a vector

Tags: regex, matlab

I have some data from a GPS receiver, however, some of the data are corrupted by extra characters. I want to extract the timestamp (the first field) and the data for the `$GPGGA` and `$GPVTG`.

To be more clear, here is a sample of the data I have in a cell array:

```
'1458937887.70818 $GPGGA,200228.90,3555.3269,N,15552.9641,A*25'
'1458937887.709668 $GPVTG,56.740,T,56.740,M,0.069,N,0.127,K,D*2D'
'1458937887.712022 ªDe¾,…´apö$™°%=HfSrîU¾Õ½ôAqö‚>1ÀàHqgu$GPGGA,200229.00,3555.3269,N,15552.9641,C*2B'
'1458937887.714071 $GPVTG,286.847,T,286.847,M,0.028,N,0.051,K,D*28'
```

As you can see, the problem here is in the third line where some strange characters appear between the timestamp and the data.

Another problem is that sometimes this third line is split into two lines, something like this:

```
'1458937887.712022 ªDe¾,…´apö$™°'
'%=HfSrîU¾Õ½ôAqö‚>1ÀàHqgu$GPGGA,200229.00,3555.3269,N,15552.9641,D*24'
```

which is making using `regexp` very hard.

In summary, I want to format the third line (in both cases) as:

```
'1458937887.712022 $GPGGA,200229.00,3555.3269,N,15552.9641,D*2R'
```

**Update:**

Thanks to @excaza, this solves the first issue (removing the garbage):

```
regexprep(str, '(?<=\d\s)(.*)(?=\$GPGGA)', '')
```

As for the second issue, @Suever's question gave me an idea by looking at the format of the data. Is it possible to solve it while reading the data from a .txt file? Something like defining the delimiter to be `*` followed by two characters and a `\n` since all packets end with this pattern?

Comment: Does the data come in as a cell array or do you create it?

Comment: You could try clearing out the garbage between the last number and `$GPGGA` with `regexprep` first: `regexprep(str, '\d\s(.*)(?=\$GPGGA)', ' ')`

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice tip. Although this removes all the garbage, it also removes the last number in the timestamp itself (i.e., the number `2` in the example above). So, I just removed the `\d` and it works to solve the first problem perfectly.

Comment: @Hamid oops, I copied the wrong one: `regexprep(str, '(?<=\d\s)(.*)(?=\$GPGGA)', '')`

Comment: @Suever: I read the data using `textscan` from a .txt file, hence it is stored in a cell array. Something like `textscan(fileID,'%s','Delimiter','\n')`

Comment: As a test, you could import line-by-line using [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) and see if that alleviates the line splitting behavior.

Comment: I have tried this already, unfortunately it does not.