# How to read data using a custom delimiter

Tags: matlab, textscan

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267887/matlab-how-to-extract-specific-data-from-a-vector?noredirect=1#comment60167130_36267887) question, I have this data sample saved in a .txt file:

```
'1458937887.70818 $GPGGA,200228.90,3555.3269,N,15552.9641,A*25'
'1458937887.709668 $GPVTG,56.740,T,56.740,M,
 0.069,N,0.127,K,D*2D'
'1458937887.712022 $GPGGA,200229.00,3555.3269,N,
 15552.9641,C*2B'
'1458937887.714071 $GPVTG,286.847,T,286.847,M,0.028,N,0.051,K,D*28'
```

I use the following to read the data:

```
textscan(fileID,'%s','Delimiter','\n')
```

However, the `\n` is not what I want. I want to define another delimiter to be a letter (alphanumeric), followed by `*`, followed by two letters (alphanumeric), then a `\n`.

**Edit:**
The main problem is that some data are saved into two lines. For example, line 2 and 3 above belongs to the same data packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion I have is to read the **entire** file as a single string.  Then what you can do is remove the new lines that are placed in the file yourself.  Once you do this, use regular expressions to insert new newlines after you find the desired pattern which is one alphanumeric character, followed by an asterisk `*` followed by two alphanumeric characters.  Once we finally have that, use `textscan` with the `Delimiter` flag to separate out the strings by the new newline characters we have put in.

First use [`fread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) to read in data from a file.  We can slightly abuse this command by reading an infinite amount of characters, which means it will read the entire file until the end.  We also need to make sure that we specify that each discrete element in this file is a character.  Once we do this, we search for any newline characters and remove them. If you are on Windows, not only does it introduce newlines but it also introduces carriage returns but the code I will write will be independent of that fact.  We do need to know that the newline is ASCII code 10 and the carriage return is ASCII code 13.  The output of `fread` will in fact be a `double` array where each element is the ASCII code of a character seen in the file.  We will use `logical` indexing to remove these elements, then use [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to search for the desired pattern and insert newline characters ourselves.  Once we do this, we finally throw this into `textscan` like how you've called it.

As such:

```
fileID = fopen('...'); %// Place filename here
str = fread(fileID, [1 inf], 'char'); %// Read in the string as one array

%// Remove newlines and carriage returns (if applicable)
str(str == 10 | str == 13) = [];

%// Search for the desired pattern and insert newlines after the pattern
out = regexprep(char(str), '\w\*\w{2}', '$0\n');

%// Finally split up the strings
txt = textscan(out, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
txt = txt{1};

%// Close the file
fclose(fileID);
```

When we use `regexprep`, we search for an alphanumeric character `\w`, followed by an asterisk `\*` (the `\` is important here because `*` is used in regex language to mean something else. To denote the actual character `*` in regex, you have to prepend with a `\` character), followed by two alphanumeric characters `\w{2}`.  The result will be these occurrences in your file removed from the strings all together.  Another intricacy is that we **must** cast to `char` to convert the string that was originally a `double` type to `char`.  Also, `textscan`'s output in this case should give you a nested cell array of one element, so we unpack the cell by referencing the first cell.  The desired output is in `txt`.

Comment: This is not actually what I want. I don't want to remove these characters. Maybe I was not clear enough. The problem is that some of the strings are read into two lines, for example, the second and third lines belong to the same data packet. That is why I want to keep reading the data until I see these characters instead of the `\n`.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Well one suggestion I have is to read the entire file as a string, replace the desired pattern with the new line then pass it through textscan. That's the only way to do it if you desire to use textscan. I'll modify my answer soon.

Comment: In fact I have no preference. I just need my code to run efficiently.